# file downloaded from mysql database using php is changed

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload, download

I'm able to upload a file to mysql but when i download it, the content changes.. example i have test.txt with

> "hello"

on it.. when i download it, the test.txt becomes

> < pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>string 'sfasfsafasfsaf' *(length=14)*
>   sfasfsafasfsaf

not sure, what's wrong..

this is my code for downloading the file:

```
<?php include("class_lib.php"); 
        $db = new database();
        $db->connect();
    if(isset($_GET["file_id"])){
                    $file_id = $_GET["file_id"];

                    $query = "SELECT filename, filetype, filesize, bin_data " .
                                "FROM file_tbl WHERE id = '$file_id'";

                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed' . mysql_error());
                    list($filename, $filetype, $filesize, $bin_data) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                     var_dump($bin_data);  

                    header("Content-length: $filesize");
                    header("Content-type: $filetype");
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
                    echo $bin_data;

            }
?>
```

for images also, it downloads but there's no image anymore.. it only shows `"no preview available"`.. is this with my download script above?
or maybe this upload script i have:

```
$fileid = (string) ($lastemp_id + 1);
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['binFile']['name']);
            $extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fileName .= "_fileid_" . $fileid;
        $fileName = $fileName.".".$extension;
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['binFile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['binFile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['binFile']['type'];
        $fileDesc = $_POST["txtDescription"];
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = addslashes($content);
                    fclose($fp);

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){ $fileName = addslashes($fileName); }     

        if (isset($fileName)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO file_tbl ";
            $sql .= "(file_desc, bin_data, filename, filesize, filetype) ";
            $sql .= "VALUES ('$fileDesc', '$content',  ";
            $sql .= "'$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType')";
            mysql_query($sql, $db->connection) or die('Error: query failed' . mysql_error()); 
            $message =  "File uploaded.<br>"; var_dump($content);
        }
        else $message = "No file uploaded. (opt)";
```

what is wrong here exactly??

Answer (score 1):

You're recklessly jamming binary data into your database without even a whiff of [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). What did you expect to happen? This short sample of code is so full of **severe** SQL injection bugs I hope for your sake it isn't deployed on the public internet.

For your own safety you should immediately stop using the creaky, old, deprecated `mysql_query` interface and spend the small amount of time necessary to switch your queries to PDO.

You would not have problems like this if you were using placeholders.

What you're seeing is probably the result of your spurious `var_dump` statement before you output your proper content.

Comment: but thanks anyways, i figured it out.. i was doing single page submission earlier that's why the original file was changed when i downloaded it..

Comment: Please pay attention to your SQL injection bugs. You really, **really** need to at least use `mysql_real_escape_string` on any and all values put into your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, if upload file is flawless.
You can encode your binary data to 64 format when insert into database and also decode before download it.

```
<?php 
ob_start();     
include("class_lib.php");
$db = new database();
$db->connect();
    if(isset($_GET["file_id"])){
          $file_id = $_GET["file_id"];
          $query = "SELECT filename, filetype, filesize, bin_data " .
                            "FROM file_tbl WHERE id = '$file_id'";

          $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed' . mysql_error());
          list($filename, $filetype, $filesize, $bin_data) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          var_dump($bin_data);  
          ob_end_clean();
          header("Content-length: $filesize");
          header("Content-type: $filetype");
          header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
          echo $bin_data;
          exit;
  }
```

?>